# Groovy/Java generate long values (min, max range)

Tags: java, groovy

I have to generate one million numbers of 64-bi signed integers. How can I pick random long value in `Long.min()` and `Long.max()` range, i.e from `0 to 2^64 - 1`?

Comment: See java.util.Random: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`new java.util.Random().nextLong()`

There's no need to specify package `java.util` when it comes to groovy.

To generate the numbers:

```
new Random().with { (1..1000000).collect { nextLong()} }
```